# Как получить первый или последний числовой элемент объекта?

Tags: javascript

Есть объект вида

```
{12859: {…}, 12860: {…}, 12861: {…}}
```

Как получить один любой элемент из него, если он неизвестен заранее?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
var obj = {12859: 1, 12860: 2, 12861: 3}
var keys = Object.keys(obj); //получаем ключи объекта в виде массива
console.log(obj[keys[0]]); // первый элемент
console.log(obj[keys[keys.length - 1]]); //последний элемент
```

Answer (score 1):

My example:
Object.keys(obj).pop()

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]